# How to tell Webpack to output nothing?

Tags: javascript, webpack, svg-sprite

I'm trying to configure `svg-sprite-loader/plugin`. I've made standalone Webpack configuration file for that task. It look into specified directory and take every `.svg` from it. The result is `icons.svg` sprite file. *BUT* Webpack also creates `.js` for every entry file. Is that possible to exlude or... delete... or whatever... those files? In other words I need only plugin output, nothing else.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. Maybe I just should programmatically delete those files after task completed?

**webpack.prod.conf.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

const webpackBaseConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf');
const webpackSpritesConfig = require('./webpack.sprites.conf');

module.exports = [
  webpackSpritesConfig,
  merge(webpackBaseConfig, {
    ...
  })
];
```

**webpack.sprites.conf.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');

function getSprites() {
  let sprites = {};

  fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/sprites'))
    .filter(file => file.match(/\.svg/))
    .forEach(file => {
      let filename = file.split('.');

      filename.pop();

      sprites[filename] = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/sprites/' + file);
    });

  return sprites;
}

module.exports = {
  entry: getSprites(),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
        options: {
          extract: true,
          spriteFilename: 'img/icons.svg'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new SpriteLoaderPlugin()]
};
```

Comment: The svg-sprite-loader itself exports js

Comment: Axnyff, is that possible to tell it not to do that?

Comment: No, webpack will always output something.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to delete those generated files after Webpack `done` hook:

**webpack.sprites.conf.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');

const EventHooksPlugin = require('event-hooks-webpack-plugin');
const { CallbackTask } = require('event-hooks-webpack-plugin/lib/tasks');

let files = [];

function getSprites() {
  let sprites = {};

  fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/sprites'))
    .filter(file => file.match(/\.svg/))
    .forEach(file => {
      let filename = file.split('.');

      filename.pop();

      files.push(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/' + filename + '.js'));
      sprites[filename] = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/sprites/' + file);
    });

  return sprites;
}

module.exports = {
  entry: getSprites(),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
        options: {
          extract: true,
          spriteFilename: 'img/icons.svg'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new SpriteLoaderPlugin(),
    new EventHooksPlugin({
      done: new CallbackTask((compiler, callback) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
          fs.unlinkSync(file);
        });

        callback();
      })
    })
  ]
};
```